# What is a connection checkout in Hibernate c3p0?

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

I am looking at the documentation of [`c3p0`](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#testConnectionOnCheckout) where they have coined the term `connection checkout`, can someone explain what it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you Ctrl-F the document, you'll find

> just prior to being handed to clients on checkout, just prior to being returned to the pool on check-in.

Check-out means getting a connection from the pool.

Check-in means giving back a connection to the pool.

Comment: Did you mean check out from database or pool (I am assuming connection pooling on application side), as pointed out at `Connections just after they are checked out from the **database**`

Comment: *Check-out means getting a connection from the pool.*. I don't know how I can be clearer than that. I used the term "pool". Not the term "database".

Comment: you were clear in your statement, but the documentation said `checked out from the database` (that was confusing)(https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#testConnectionOnCheckout), I think you are pointing at https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ConnectionCustomizer.html#onCheckOut-java.sql.Connection-java.lang.String-